# Is there a way to extract the coordinates from cv2.rectangle from the opencv object tracker kcf?

Tags: python, opencv

What I am trying to do is extract the coordinates from a bounding box made by cv2.rectangle. The bounding box is created using HOG from which cv2.rectangle is made:

```
        rects, weights = hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(8,8))
        rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
        for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in rects:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

I then use KCF tracker to track this bounding box, is there a way to extract the coordinate data of the KCF tracker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, with the update function

```
(success, box) = tracker.update(frame)
# check to see if the tracking was a success
if success:
    (x, y, w, h) = [int(v) for v in box]
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),
        (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Comment: Whenever I get the x and y coordinates to print it is a constant number, which I believe to be the input bounding box coordinates. I can't seem to get it to update after this first instance in my loop.

Comment: Can you show me more of your code, at least the loop part?